# DevExpress multi-channel platform

Tags: visual-studio, mobile, devexpress

i've just started using the devExpress multi-channel platform which released earlier this month,for applications in all mobile platforms.The thing is i've never used DevExpress components,or html5 or javascript.Can you point articles that would help me get started?Thank you for your time.

Comment: DevExpress has got good support. You can get everything in their documentation.

Comment: ok i'll try that,you mean on their official page right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [DXTREME](http://www.devexpress.com/Subscriptions/DXperience/dxtreme.xml) you can start from here (HTML5/JS): [DXTREME Learning Center](http://help.devexpress.com/HTML/#!Overview)

P.S. I suggest you use [DevExpress Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center) to get official and guaranteed assistance on the use of DevExpress products. Note that FULL SUPPORT IS FREE during the evaluation period (30 days).

Comment: ok thanks,you mena 30 days since i've got it activated right?